# Remove root tag in JSON using XSLT when converting XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a XML to JSON using XSLT definition. I have got the required output but i want a root tag from my json output to be removed while converting please help me out with this.

**XML input**

```
<ArrayOfApiInvoiceReport xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RepSpark.WebServices.Models">
    <BillingAddress1>10 N LUMINA AVE</BillingAddress1>
    <BillingAddress2/>
    <BillingCity>WRIGHTSVILLE BEACH</BillingCity>
    <BillingCountry>US</BillingCountry>
    <BillingCustomerCode>3003800</BillingCustomerCode>
    <BillingCustomerName>SWEETWATER SURF SHOP</BillingCustomerName>
    <BillingState>NC</BillingState>
    <BillingZip>28480</BillingZip>
    <InvoiceAmount>372.72</InvoiceAmount>
    <InvoiceCreatedDate>20141110</InvoiceCreatedDate>
    <InvoiceItems>
        <InvoiceItemSizes>
            <InvoiceLineNumber>1</InvoiceLineNumber>
            <InvoicedQuantity>3</InvoicedQuantity>
            <SizeCode>L</SizeCode>
            <UPC>9348282095644</UPC>
        </InvoiceItemSizes>
        <InvoiceLineNumber>1</InvoiceLineNumber>
        <InvoiceNumber>101000005</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceItems>
</ArrayOfApiInvoiceReport
```

**XSLT used**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>[{
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
}]</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
</xsl:template>
```

**Current JSON output**

```
"ArrayOfApiInvoiceReport" : [{

    "BillingAddress1" : "10 N LUMINA AVE",
    "BillingAddress2" : "",
    "BillingCity" : "WRIGHTSVILLE BEACH",
    "BillingCountry" : "US",
    "BillingCustomerCode" : "3003800",
    "BillingCustomerName" : "SWEETWATER SURF SHOP",
    "BillingState" : "NC",
    "BillingZip" : "28480",
    "InvoiceAmount" : "372.72",
    "InvoiceCreatedDate" : "20141110",
    "InvoiceItems" : [{

    "InvoiceItemSizes" : [{

    "InvoiceLineNumber" : "1",
    "InvoicedQuantity" : "3",
    "SizeCode" : "L",
    "UPC" : "9348282095644"
}],
    "InvoiceLineNumber" : "1",
    "InvoiceNumber" : "101000005",
    "InvoicedQuantity" : "3",
```

**Required Output is a JSON without `"ArrayOfApiInvoiceReport"`[{**

```
"BillingAddress1": "10 N LUMINA AVE",
"BillingAddress2": "",
"BillingCity": "WRIGHTSVILLE BEACH",
"BillingCountry": "US",
"BillingCustomerCode": "3003800",
"BillingCustomerName": "SWEETWATER SURF SHOP",
"BillingState": "NC",
"BillingZip": "28480",
"InvoiceAmount": "372.72",
"InvoiceCreatedDate": "20141110",
"InvoiceItems": [
  {
    "InvoiceItemSizes": [
      {
        "InvoiceLineNumber": "1",
        "InvoicedQuantity": "3",
        "SizeCode": "L",
        "UPC": "9348282095644"
      }
    ],
    "InvoiceLineNumber": "1",
    "InvoiceNumber": "101000005",
    "InvoicedQuantity": "3",
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Required output is without "ArrayOfApiInvoiceReport". the output should start with [{"BillingAddress1": "10 N ...............}]

Comment: Siva, I have some points on your question. The XML is invalid as "InvoiceItems" node is incorrectly closed; on the output JSON there is no closure for "InvoiceItems" ; There is an additional "InvoicedQuantity" at the end with no corresponding element in the input XML - is that calculated?; and the JSON ends with a comma - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my points on the original question.

Here is a stylesheet that converts the XML into JSON without the containing node.

This stylesheet also omits the final comma. If you want to keep that you will need to add it in.

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 

   >


                <xsl:output method="text" />
                <xsl:variable name="nl"><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="tb"><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

                <xsl:template match="/*">


                    <!-- Open the root array -->
                    <xsl:text>[{</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />

                    <!-- Process all the child nodes of the root -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="subitem" >
                        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$tb" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>

                    <!-- Close the root array -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>


                </xsl:template>




                <xsl:template match="*" mode="subitem" >
                    <!-- child element at any level. The indent parameter allows for better layout of the output JSON -->
                    <xsl:param name="indent"></xsl:param>

                    <!-- newindent is used as the indent for children of this node -->
                    <xsl:variable name="newindent"><xsl:value-of select="$indent" /><xsl:value-of select="$tb"/></xsl:variable>

                    <!-- output the name of this node in quotes, ready for the content to follow -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$indent" /><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()" /><xsl:text>" :</xsl:text>

                    <!-- check if this node has children, if not, simply output the text value, otherwise outoput an array -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test=" count( ./* ) = 0 ">
                            <!-- This is a text value only -->
                                <xsl:text> "</xsl:text>

                                <!-- Make sure that any embedded quotes are escaped -->
                                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="replace">"</xsl:with-param>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="by">\"</xsl:with-param>

                                </xsl:call-template>
                                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

                                <!-- check if we need a comma and a new line, not required if this is the last output value -->
                                <xsl:if test=" position() != last() ">
                                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                                </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <!-- This node has children, so we need to process them as an array -->

                                <!-- Array opening -->
                                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="$newindent" /><xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$nl" />

                                    <!-- Process all the elements in the array (recursive call to this template) -->
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="subitem" >
                                        <xsl:with-param name="indent"><xsl:value-of select="$newindent" /></xsl:with-param>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>

                                <!-- Close the array -->
                                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" /><xsl:value-of select="$newindent" /><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$nl" /><xsl:value-of select="$indent" /><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>

                                <!-- If this is not the last node then we need a comma and line feed -->
                                <xsl:if test=" position() != last() ">
                                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />
                                </xsl:if>

                        </xsl:otherwise>

                    </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:template>


                <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
                <!-- This code provided thanks to @codesling on stackoverflow -->
                  <xsl:param name="text" />
                  <xsl:param name="replace" />
                  <xsl:param name="by" />
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                      <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
                      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With (corrected) XML the output is:

```
 [{
    "BillingAddress1" : "10 N LUMINA AVE",
    "BillingAddress2" : "",
    "BillingCity" : "WRIGHTSVILLE BEACH",
    "BillingCountry" : "US",
    "BillingCustomerCode" : "3003800",
    "BillingCustomerName" : "SWEETWATER SURF SHOP",
    "BillingState" : "NC",
    "BillingZip" : "28480",
    "InvoiceAmount" : "372.72",
    "InvoiceCreatedDate" : "20141110",
    "InvoiceItems" :[
        {
        "InvoiceItemSizes" :[
            {
            "InvoiceLineNumber" : "1",
            "InvoicedQuantity" : "3",
            "SizeCode" : "L",
            "UPC" : "9348282095644"
            }
        ],
        "InvoiceLineNumber" : "1",
        "InvoiceNumber" : "101000005"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: In the above example we have only one item in the InvoiceItem level. If when we are converting xml to json we are getting the Item in single [ ]. The same case if we have multiple items I am getting the output as

Comment: In the above example we have only one item in the InvoiceItem level. If when we are converting xml to json we are getting the Item in single [ ]. The same case if we have multiple items I am getting the output as "InvoiceItem" :[{ }], "InvoiceItem" :[{}], "InvoiceItems" :[{}]. I want it to be like "InvoiceItem" : [{}, {}, {}] i dont want it to have multiple InvoiceItem tags. The input xml looks like <InvoiceItem></InvoiceItem> <InvoiceItem></InvoiceItem> <InvoiceItem></InvoiceItem> . I need to use XSLT for getting it as required because i cant change the XML. Please help me.

Comment: Could you please help me in removing the Root element in the xslt which i have pasted. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @SivaSwarna where are the <InvoiceItem> nodes in the XML? There are none in the example XML. Please provide an example XML with multiple <InvoiceItem> nodes exactly as you expect to receive it.