# how to make specific node as list in xslt and i want output in json

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml and i want its output as json using xslt.
i found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450607/remove-root-tag-in-json-using-xslt-when-converting-xml-to-json?answertab=active#comment49099770_30456220) of it but i need some changes which i am unable to do it because i am new in xslt. in this solution i want some nested tags as list in json but this solution gives all the nested tags in xml as list in json which i dont want. the main point is i want to remove extra [].
help me please

my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><User>
<MaritalStatus>Single</MaritalStatus>
<Name>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>def</MiddleName>
    <LastName>ghi</LastName>
</Name>
<Relative>
    <Father>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>def</MiddleName>
            <LastName>ghi</LastName>
        </Name>
    </Father>
    <Mother>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>def</MiddleName>
            <LastName>ghi</LastName>
        </Name>
    </Mother>
    <Sibling>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>def</MiddleName>
            <LastName>ghi</LastName>
        </Name>

    </Sibling>
</Relative>
<Friend>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>def</MiddleName>
        <LastName>ghi</LastName>
    </Name>
</Friend></User>
```

the solution giving me which i mentioned is giving me json

```
[{
"MaritalStatus": "Single",
"Name": [
  {
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "MiddleName": "def",
    "LastName": "ghi"
  }
],
"Relative": [
  {
    "Father": [
      {
        "Name": [
          {
            "FirstName": "abc",
            "MiddleName": "def",
            "LastName": "ghi"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Mother": [
      {
        "Name": [
          {
            "FirstName": "abc",
            "MiddleName": "def",
            "LastName": "ghi"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Sibling": [
      {
        "Name": [
          {
            "FirstName": "ewqrew",
            "MiddleName": "defasdfadsf",
            "LastName": "ghiqwerwqer"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
],
"Friend": [
  {
    "Name": [
      {
        "FirstName": "asd",
        "MiddleName": "ghd",
        "LastName": "rtu"
      }
    ]
  }
]}]
```

but the output i want is

```
{
"MaritalStatus": "Single",
"Name":
  {
    "FirstName": "abc",
    "MiddleName": "def",
    "LastName": "ghi"
  },
"Relative": [
  {
    "Father":
      {
        "Name":
          {
            "FirstName": "abc",
            "MiddleName": "def",
            "LastName": "ghi"
          }
      },
    "Mother":
      {
        "Name":
          {
            "FirstName": "abc",
            "MiddleName": "def",
            "LastName": "ghi"
          }
      },
    "Sibling": [
      {
        "Name":
          {
            "FirstName": "ewqrew",
            "MiddleName": "defasdfadsf",
            "LastName": "ghiqwerwqer"
          }
      }
    ]
  }
],
"Friend": [
  {
    "Name": 
      {
        "FirstName": "asd",
        "MiddleName": "ghd",
        "LastName": "rtu"
      }
  }
]}
```

Comment: Please submit your own XSLT as you use it. Pointing to another question/solution does not help.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450607/remove-root-tag-in-json-using-xslt-when-converting-xml-to-json?answertab=active#comment49099770_30456220]
i have tried the solution of this link. but i want the the output that i have mention above

Answer (score 0):

With Saxon Home You can take advantage of the XPath 3.1 function `fn:xml-to-json`. I'll include a very simple solution suitable to understand the thing.

Download Saxon Home and create the xslt (test.xsl) below. Run

```
java -jar Saxon-HE-9.7.0-7.jar -s:<your-xml-file> -xsl:test.xsl
```

(Replace the Saxon jar file name with your downloaded version)

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Naive approach -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="xmljson">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="fn:xml-to-json($xmljson)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="User">
        <fn:map>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fn:map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MaritalStatus">
        <fn:string key="MaritalStatus">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fn:string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <fn:map key="Name">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fn:map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FirstName">
        <fn:string key="FirstName">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fn:string>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- TODO (naive approach)-->
    <xsl:template match="Relative" />
    <xsl:template match="Friend" />
    <xsl:template match="MiddleName" />
    <xsl:template match="LastName" />

    <!-- TODO better way: fiddle with copy local-name() and more -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Read about `fn:xml-to-json`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#json-functions)

Good luck!

Comment: is there any generic solution? which i customize that solution or any guideline????

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you mean by "generic solution". `fn:xml-to-json` is generic. Given your initial question and XML sample you just don't need any complex generic stylesheet. A "few-liner" will do fine. Do you want a XSLT stylesheet which transforms an arbitrary complex XML (attributes, data types, comments, ...) input to JSON? I'm not aware if this exists or if it is possible/makes sense (never searched and never thought about this). Perhaps You need something like [http://www.jsonml.org/]. Please detail your question to reflect all your needs and skills. That helps helping You.